# Cassandra copy-from more than 100 columns

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I was going through [cassandra-docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) in how to use copy-from and copy-to commands to get the data in to the cluster.

Example from docs:

`COPY airplanes (name, manufacturer, year, mach) FROM 'temp.csv';`

where I have to mention the column names in the parenthesis. what if I have more than 100 columns? I can't keep entering the column names which is tedious task. Is there any other way to achieve this.

Also what are the other sources from where I can load the data ex: excel, other db or xml file etc.

Comment: At some point you will be required to enter the column names. Either in defining the column family or in the copy script with `cqlsh`. Do you have a list of the column names somewhere that you can copy and paste?

Answer (score 2):

It is not a Cassandra problem but a user-friendly feature of `cqlsh` which lets you import data from a few file formats. If you want something fancier, write your own Python script (that's just what `cqlsh` is doing).

From Datastax Academy:

> Note: copy does not require columns name when the target table schema and source CSV file columns match respectively.

```
COPY videos FROM 'videos.csv';
```

Comment: Starting from the title, then your link, then an explanation why it is not possible (but trivial with your own script), which also cover your question "Is there any other way to achieve this.", your last sentence is also covered (although it's duplicating the DOC - your link, but that's nice because duplicating data is the Cassandra way to go). You're welcome.

Comment: What part? There's not much to say about it, `cqlsh` offers some limited support to import/export in a few file format, I think that's just a way to play around in dev with different schema and populate the database, or to export a small bunch of data (errors, etc.).